# Uniquely identifying and lexicographically sorting transactions

Tags: web3js, transactions, blocks

Is `event.blockNumber + '-' + event.logIndex` unique for an Ethereum transaction (that is no two different transactions having it the same)?

If not, is `event.blockNumber + '-' + event.logIndex + event.blockHash` unique?

Please also help (with JavaScript) to convert these values into such strings that the order of the transactions in time (approximate) would match the resulting lexicographical order of the values.

I think, somethings like: `toHex(event.blockNumber) + '-' + toHex(event.logIndex)`. How to define `toHex()`?

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple transactions in a block so you can't use the block number as a unique identifier. Furthermore validated blocks may get discarded and replaced by other blocks due to consensus mechanism.

To uniquely identify a block you should use its `block hash`. And in the same way, to uniquely identify a transaction, you can use its `transaction hash` - this is unique across all blocks.

To sort transactions you can use the transaction timestamp directly as it's in unix time - for example `1593888786`. This is the time when the transaction's block was mined. This will be the same value for all transactions inside a single block. So something like `tx timestamp + '-' + tx hash` should work for sorting.